# How can i show all my DataSets in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, listview, combobox

How can i populate my ComboBox with all the datasets that  are in my project

My Code

```
 foreach (DataTable table in DataSet.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    {
                        object item = row[column];

                    }
                }
                comboBox1.Items.Add(table.TableName);
            }
```

Comment: This code fills the combobox with table names. What have you tried for the rest? Is there a problem? What's not working as expected? You should be looking at the events for the combobox and using one to detect when a table is selected so you can populate the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill the combobox with tableNames only.

```
foreach (DataTable table in DataSet.Tables)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(table.TableName);
        }
```

Then you need to code the Select event of your combobox which could look something like this.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //fill listview with items that belong to the combobox.SelectedItem
    //since you filled the combobox with table.TableName, the name will be in .SelectedItem
}
```

And don't forget

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: i dont wanna fill the combobox with tablename i wanna show the database names in the combobox

Comment: Whatever you fill it with, it's what you'll use to populate the listView. If table.TableName is a database name, then you will fill the listView with said database content.

Answer (score 0):

modify your query for have all data in result of your sql command, like this

```
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int i = 0;
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
        sql = "select au_id,au_lname from authors";
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "au_id";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "au_lname";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
```